# .NET web API and .NET worker in the same project

Tags: .net, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, webapi, worker

Is it possible to host a web API and a worker in the same .net project?

Being possible, is it a good practice?

I have a project that started as a web API and added a Kafka consumer, but now I'm not sure if both services will work fine

Comment: What do you mean by "worker", exactly? (But in general, yes, ever since ASP.NET Core 3 moved from `IWebHost` to `IHost` we can use things like `IBackgroundService` for [other, non-HTTP-related-things](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-6.0&tabs=visual-studio) - but be careful because your process is still subject to [IIS process recycling](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/iis/6.0-sdk/ms525803(v=vs.90)), so be prepared for your process to be restarted, or even shut-down _without_ being restarted, without warning.

Comment: Possible, but you go back the classic Hangfire situation if deployed to Windows/IIS, which most people are going to avoid, https://blog.lextudio.com/unpleasant-facts-about-hangfire-632a3228ff8a

Comment: @canha Did you get any feedback, I have the same doubt